# Data Recovery from deleted PopOS

Tags: linux, data-recovery, pop-os

I have a SSD and a 1TB Hard drive in my PC. SSD had the Windows 10 and Hard Drive had Linux(PopOS). I was installing the new windows and accidentally deleted the hard drive having the Linux at windows partition menu. Now my hard drive is a complete 1TB unallocated drive. Please i just want to get my codes which were inside the Downloads folder of the PopOS. Is there any way to get my data back, i have already tried few data recovery software in windows 10. but they are not showing my data especially .py files.

Comment: Whatever Windows overwrote is gone. You can try testdisk and deeper search, if it finds files, immediately copy those to another drive. Otherwise you can try photorec which on 1TB drive will take a very long time. And needs large amount of space on another drive to copy data into. It only recovers files by extension. I had many text files and had to spend days sorting. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery & 
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk & http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step & http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/After_Using_PhotoRec